# I want to compile my python project and i don't know how to do that

Tags: python, makefile, compilation, pyinstaller, exe

I want to compile all this into a python exe
[folder and file png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLS6C.png)

Can you guys give me the full command on how can i compile it

Comment: It's because you can't. Python is a script language, there are some hacks to try and make an .exe out of it but thats not really compiling.

Comment: to compile a executable outof python code, its required to use pyinstaller. it will build a  single package or python executable including python env.  https://pypi.org/project/pyinstaller/

Answer (score -1):

run the main file from the terminal, all files are probably linked through it.
to run the file go to the directory where all of your files are present and type: `python main.py`